# How to receive ajax request using django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have the following JQuery Ajax request on my template that i want pass to my django view,

```
function loginUser(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url :"/login-user/",
            data:"title=ajax call",
            datatype:"json",
            error:function(data){alert('Error:'+data);}
            success:function(data){alert('OK!'+data.message+','+data.code);}
          });
        }
```

my django view looks like this:

```
def login_user(request):
    print "garbage"
    print request.GET['title']
    return_dict = {'message': 'bla bla bla','code':324}
    json=serialize("json",return_dict)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/x-javascript"
```

When i call the ajax function i get the following error:

**Error: [object XMLHttpRequest]**

and on the django side i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 281, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 417, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "c:\python26\lib\socket.py", line 297, in write
    self.flush()
  File "c:\python26\lib\socket.py", line 284, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

What am i missing on this call?

Gath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is serializing the dictionary. When I tested your code, I edited it to look like this and it worked:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
def login_users(request):
    print "garbage"
    print request.GET['title']
    return_dict = {'message': 'bla bla bla','code':324}
    json = simplejson.dumps(return_dict)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

Also make sure you are passing in a value for title in your GET query string. I ran into that as well (may need to be error checked). It helps if you use a tool like Firebug, or even the Webkit Inspector. That way you can view the HTML error pages that Django is returning from your XHR request.

Comment: @jcady- "Also make sure you are passing in a value for title in your GET query string.." what does that mean? In the question asked the person is using POST!!